# Sum column values for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would sum each row of this dataframe based on a column.

Input Dataframe:

```
    a   b
0   red 5
1   red 8
2   red 2
3   red 4
4   red 1
```

I used this code to sum values `sumcol = df['b'].sum()` but this sum the entire column I would a value for each row -1 in a new column.

Expected Dataframe:

```
    a   b   c
0   red 5   15
1   red 8   7
2   red 2   5
3   red 4   1
4   red 1   0
```

Comment: @DarrylG my start dataframe is the first I want to create new column `['c']` that sum each row in column `['b']` -1, the second dataframe in the post is the result that I am looking for

Comment: @DarrylG He wants to get summation for every `i+1:` values of b. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply lambda` with `axis=1`. 
`x.name` will give you the current index for each row. Simple make slices for each row using `x.name+1:` which means get all below rows.

```
df["c"] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.name+1:,"b"].sum(),axis=1)

print(df)

         a  b   c
    0   red 5   15
    1   red 8   7
    2   red 2   5
    3   red 4   1
    4   red 1   0
```

And if you wants to get summation/number_of_values which seems like a case of `mean()` then try:

```
df["c"] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.name+1:,"b"].mean(),axis=1)
print(df)

         a  b    c
    0   red 5   3.750000
    1   red 8   2.333333
    2   red 2   2.500000
    3   red 4   1.000000
    4   red 1   NaN
```

Comment: Great it works, if I would add divide by the rows counted? So will be in `['c']` 15/4, 7/3, 5/2, 1/1, 0/0. Can I use `count()`?

Comment: df["c"] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.name+1:,"b"].sum(),axis=1) / df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.name+1:,"b"].count(),axis=1) tried it and works! Thanks!

Comment: Its seems like a case of `mean()`. See my edit for optimal solution.